# jQuery post request works only on FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, post, request

I'm trying to make a post request with jQuery to check doubles before sending form, but it works only on FireFox browser. Does anybody know what the problem is?

This is a different script, but the same result, I tested it too, and I have the same problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug1xl379Yi8

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file").change(function() {

      var file = $("#file").val();

      $.post("filedoublecheck.php", {
        file: file
      }, function(output) {
        if (output == 1) {
          alert("File already exists!");
        }
      });

    });
  });

</script>
```

```html
**General**:
Remote Address:0.0.0.0:443
Request URL:https://example.net/filedoublecheck.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK


**Response Headers**:
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Tue, 07 Apr 2015 18:12:26 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19


**Request Headers**:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:92
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:******
Host:example.net
Origin:https://example.net
Referer:https://example.net/upload.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any error messages in the console, any errors in the network tab?

Comment: Not nearly enough information given. You need to inspect the actual request in network tab of dev tools console for more details and add an error handler to your ajax

Comment: I can't see a respone on chrome console but on firefox firebug, it's a "1" for true. There are no errors...

Comment: There you can see what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug1xl379Yi8

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution...  It doesn't work on file inputs. I made a capture function for a hidden input and now it works...

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file").change(function() {

      var file = $("#dispName").val();

      $.post("filedoublecheck.php", {
        file: file
      }, function(output) {
        if (output == 1) {
          alert("File already exists!");
        }
      });

    });
  });


  function getStats(fName) {

    fullName = fName;
    shortName = fullName.match(/[^\/\\]+$/);
    document.forms.upload.dispName.value = shortName
  }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="dispName" id="dispName" />
```